# UserWarning: torchaudio C++ extension is not available

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, pytorch, torchaudio

can someone please help me out with this UserWarning in torchaudio?

**ErrorMessage:**

```
C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\extension\extension.py:14:
UserWarning: torchaudio C++ extension is not available.
  warnings.warn('torchaudio C++ extension is not available.')
```

Thank's in advance!

Comment: You probably have to install torchaudio extension.... You can open that file mentioned in your comment and check what triggers that message.

Comment: wich extension do you mean? like pip install torchaudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/backend.html says like this:

Availability

"sox" and "sox_io" backends require C++ extension module, which is included in Linux/macOS binary distributions. These backends are not available on Windows.

So you have a wrong operating system or backend selected. Depends point of view :)

Comment: ok thank you very much do you know how to set up one of those backends:)?

Comment: Check the link above.

Comment: Even installing that does not stop the warning for me.  Even importing torchaudio gives that warning