# Torchaudio C++ extension is not available - Python

Tags: python, pytorch, torchaudio

Having just started learning Torchaudio, I got this error. I fixed the first part but even after some deep internet surfing, I can't find a fix. I use Windows 10.

```
C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda39\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\extension\extension.py:13: UserWarning: torchaudio C++ extension is not available.
  warnings.warn('torchaudio C++ extension is not available.')
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/backend.html

[UserWarning: torchaudio C++ extension is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475868/userwarning-torchaudio-c-extension-is-not-available)

as @ex4 said this extencion is not avalible on windows

Comment: Do you know why they've done that and when it'll be implemented or is Linux the only sensible option?

Comment: @LambSauce i guess it was just made for linux